# every 10 tr using 10n jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```js
$('tr.include:nth-child(10n)').addClass('bottom');
```

```css
.bottom {
  color: red;
}
.skip {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>




  <tr class='skip'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='skip'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='skip'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I want to select every 10 tr in my table the first 10 works fine the next are not.(after first 10 I dynamically add 3 more tr for header) the next 10 are affected by the header and im not selecting the next 10. I have specified the class to be selected but it still is choosing only 7 from the said class. It is including the added header. I want to skip the added header. *What I want is only select every 10 from the class include.* **It should not include the class skip**

Comment: whether all the tr elements will have the `include` class\

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes they will have class include but there will also be added tr with skip class. the problem is that it is counting the class skip in every 10

Comment: In that case you can't use `:nth-selector`

Comment: @ArunPJohny that is what i am using right sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a manual filter

```js
$('tr.include').filter(function(i) {
  return (i + 1) % 10 == 0
}).addClass('bottom');
```

```css
.bottom {
  color: red;
}
.skip {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>




  <tr class='skip'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='skip'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='skip'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='include'>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Well, this is the solution.

Comment: just a thought i here is index based meaning at first value is 0?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? Why not just `i % 10 == 0` ?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal i dont understand as well but it does work lol if i can comment an image i would have comment the meme `the code works i dont have idea how code dont work i dont have idea how` lol

Comment: i have read the comment i do understand it now. should not have deleted it it was the explanation i was after :)

Comment: @BhojendraNepal because filter starts with index `0`, so equivalent of `:nth-child(10n)` will be at index `9, 19, 29... etc`

Comment: Oh! forget that. Got it now.

Comment: @BrownmanRevival the `i>0` is not required since we have `i+1`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I was also confused with i>0.